# Trying to fix Dell active pen but Python driver won't run

Tags: python, dell, inspiron, stylus

I'm very new to Linux and have absolutely no programming background, so apologies if there's an obvious answer here that I missed.

My computer is an Inspiron 7391 2-in-1. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

My Dell active pen isn't registering pressure differences. I tried it in both Krita and MyPaint. I searched and saw that this has been asked before, but the solution I found hasn't worked.

I tried to run the python driver found on this post ([Microsoft Pen Protocol support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189075/microsoft-pen-protocol-support)) and it didn't work. I have Python 3.8.5 installed.

I ran this line in my terminal:
`python3 pen_pressure.py`

And this is the return I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pen_pressure.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libevdev
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libevdev'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [related python3 evdev packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python3%20evdev) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-libevdev python3-evdev
```

Comment: That fixed that particular problem! Thanks for the help. It's still throwing errors, but at least they're different errors...